# Write a file from garbled data of GuzzleHttp, getContents (GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)

Tags: php, guzzle

What I've been trying is to have a file from a data, which is supposed to be readable.

Here is a line which is using Google Drive API.

```
$result = $this->service->files->export("ID", 'mimeType', array(
        'alt' => 'media'))
          ->getBody()
          ->getContents();
```

`$result` gets an object of `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response`. This is originally a readable `Google.doc` file. However, the `$result` is garbled, and I confirmed it with `var_dump()`.

Does anyone have an idea of converting (or restoring) `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response` objects into a readable file?
Also, I'd appreciate if you'd give an idea as to saving the restored `$result` as a doc, pdf or any other major format.

*FYI: I'm using Laravel 5, which has GuzzleHttp.*

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the getContents with read().

This worked for me:

```
$file = $service->files->export($request->id, 'application/pdf', array('alt' => 'media' ));
$size = $file->getBody()->getSize();
$content = $file->getBody()->read($size);
```